# Problems getting device orientation data for android

Tags: android, orientation, android-sensors, device-orientation

I'm new to the forum and to android development.

I've been trying to get device orientation data but seem to be doing something wrong.  I've been following this link's tutorial: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg23415.html .

However, the line

```
sensorManager =  (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

gives me an error that SENSOR_SERVICE is not a valid variable, so I found that it is a public static variable of the Context class so I used

```
sensorManager =  (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

this gives me an error that getSystemService(String) is not a method of my current class.  I understand now that getSystemService(String) is a method of Context and so my questions are

1) what is the - I presume it's a cast - `(SensorManager)` doing in front of the method call?

2) do I have to get my current context and run the method on that? if so how?

I'm sure I'm overthinking this but any help and patience is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just change the name "sensorManager " to "msensor "because sensorManager
bydefault Manager didn't use as variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) what is the - I presume it's a cast - (SensorManager) doing in front of the method call?

That is indeed a cast. It's necessary because `getSystemService` is declared to return an undifferentiated `Object` type (even though it obviously returns something more specific).

> 2) do I have to get my current context and run the method on that? if so how?

In a custom `View` class, you can use `getContext()`. If this code is part of another kind of custom class, you can pass the context in the constructor. I recommend using `getApplicationContext()` when saving the context as a member field, as `Activity` contexts should be free to be garbage collected if the activity dies from, say, an orientation change to the device.

Comment: 1) thanks that makes sense
2) I'm currently writing a game using cocos2D and I have placed this code in the constructor of a subclass of CCLayer. I did this since this is the only class that needs access to the sensors and which will make it easy to turn the sensors off when I'm not using them.  Your answer makes me think that I should put it in the GameActivity class (which is also what I've seen in the tutorials) instead then? If so, how will I access data from my CCLayer subclass? What is the conventional way to implement orientation sensors in cocos2D in android?

Comment: @mknutso2 - I haven't programmed in cocos2D for Android, but as I understand it, you can get a `Context` object using `CCDirector.sharedDirector().context()`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think about using CCDirector but it makes sense that it would be there.  The problem I have is that in my probject .context() isn't a method of CCDirector but this may be because I have an outdated build of cocos2D.  could you tell me how you found that method?

Comment: @mknutso2 - Sure. I looked in the [source for CCAccelerometerDispatcher](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/branches/moandroid/src/com/moandroid/cocos2d/events/CCAccelerometerDispatcher.java?r=103), which popped up about halfway down the page in a Google search for _cocos2d android sensor_. I figured that an accelerometer dispatcher would need access to a context to get hold of the accelerometer data.

Answer (score 0):

yes, getSystemService() is a method of Context, to get Context, use either,

```
getApplicationContext();
```

or, use your current activity or service, object to get context by:

```
ThisService.this.getSystemService();
```

or

```
ThisActivity.this.getSystemService();
```

Comment: Neither one of these are working.  Neither ThisService or ThisActivity are showing up as valid commands.  I'm trying to run the code inside the constructor of a CCLayer object in a cocos2D project if this makes a difference.

Comment: ThisService or ThisActivity the name of application components, see application components, Which may be activity name or service name your code resides in, dont know much about cocos2D